# Time Code Comparison

Tags: excel, excel-formula, comparison

I have a workbook that contains two sheets "Sign-In" and "Sign-Out". I have Last Name, First Name, ID, Date, and Time on each. I am trying to figure out the best way to compare the two sheets so that I can combine the data to tally hours worked each day.

I have tried to combine the ID and Date into one field and then run a INDEX | MATCH on between the sheets. I am comparing the two thinking that if the person signed in on a specific day then they should have a sign out on the same day. It is close but contains gaps that it says are N/A but that I can look at and see are true. So I am thinking that my hypothesis is wrong and I am not returning what I think I should be returning.

A:Timestamp B:LastName C:FirstName D:ID E:Blank F:Date G:Time H:Blank I:Comparison Data J:INDEX|MATCH Formula

My INDEX | MATCH formula looks like this:

```
=INDEX('Sign-Out'!G2:G1265,MATCH(I2,'Sign-Out'!I2:I1265,0))
```

I am not sure what I need to do here to get the results I am looking for in my table. Any help is appreciated...

Link to Sample Workbook: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c3tA3jZghFhZzic4xWKVDhkYNlJeppv-/view?usp=sharing

Expected outcome is to have sign-in times match up to sign-out times on the same day.  There are holes in the data but I expected that all data that can match will match.

Comment: Needs sample data and expected results.

Comment: I have added sample data and expected results @tigeravatar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your provided sample workbook, you don't need a Comparison column at all, so can get rid of that entirely.  I would make column H on your "Sign-In" sheet a "Time-Out" column, and then use this formula in cell H2 and copy down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Sign-Out'!D:D,D2,'Sign-Out'!F:F,F2)=0,"No Sign-Out Time",MOD(SUMIFS('Sign-Out'!A:A,'Sign-Out'!D:D,D2,'Sign-Out'!F:F,F2),1))
```

Make sure to format the cells as Time `[$-409]h:mm AM/PM;@` so that they display the results properly.

Comment: Seems to do exactly as expected...  Thanks  I figured I was over thinking it.